# Configuration tree : add conditional validation

Tags: symfony, configuration, tree

I'm trying to create a bundle to manage a menu which can be configured via config files.

So I have wrote some configuration constraints in my `class DependencyInjection\Configuration`.

The needed configuration is an array of items which must be added to the menu. Each item can have 3 different types (`link`, `link_notification`, `widget`). And for each type, item needs other attributes (like `route`, `label`, etc.).

Example of configuration:

```
menu:
    utilities:
        - { type: link, icon: icon_name, label: text, route: { name: route_name, params: {} } }
        - { type: link_notification, notification: notification_text }
        - { type: widget, controller: controller_name }
```

I'm stuck because I can't find how to define different array constraints for each type.

I can't find a way to translate condition:

```
IF type == "link" THEN scalarNode "icon" IS REQUIRED AND scalarNode "label" IS REQUIRED ...
```

Configuration file looks like this:

```
public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('aiomedia_menu');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('utilities')
                    ->prototype('array')
                        ->children()
                            ->enumNode('type')
                                ->values(array ('link', 'link_notification', 'widget'))
                                ->isRequired()
                            ->end()
                        ->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
```

I have seen methods `->ifXXX() [...] ->then()` in Symfony2 documentation, but I can't figure out how to use them in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like: (not tested, but it gives you some direction to look for)

```php
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('utilities')
            ->prototype('array')
                ->validation()
                    ->ifTrue(function ($v) {
                        if (!is_array($v)) {
                            return true;
                        }

                        switch ($v['type']) {
                            case 'link':
                                $requiredSettings = array('icon', 'label', 'route');
                                break;

                            case 'link_notification':
                                $requiredSettings = array('notification');
                                break;

                            case 'widget':
                                $requiredSettings = array('controller');
                                break;
                        }

                        foreach ($requiredSettings as $setting) {
                            if (!array_key_exists($setting, $v)) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }

                        return true;
                    })
                    ->thenInvalid('Missing required options for "%s"')
                ->end()
                ->children()
                    ->enumNode('type')
                        ->values(array ('link', 'link_notification', 'widget'))
                        ->isRequired()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end();
```